# R: how to relocate values?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two data matrix.

```
set.seed(1)
df<-matrix(sample(1:1000, 20),nrow=4)
colnames(df)<-c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")

> df
      V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
[1,] 266 201 625 679 707
[2,] 372 894  62 380 976
[3,] 572 940 204 760 374
[4,] 906 657 175 491 763

loc<-c("V1","V3","V5","V4","V2",
       "V2","V4","V5","V3","V1",
       "V5","V1","V2","V4","V3",
       "V5","V3","V1","V2","V4")
```

What I want is to compare column names in `df` with names in `loc` and relocate values in `df` as indicated in `loc`

The result I expect to have should look like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  266  625  707  679  201
[2,]  894  380  976   62  372
[3,]  374  572  940  760  204
[4,]  763  175  906  657  491
```

Any helps are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please have a look your expected answer? It seems to me that column `4` and `5` are swapped in your expected result.

Comment: @MKR Thanks for catching it up. it is corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option can be to use `sapply` to get corresponding columns(based on `loc`) from `df` for each row.

```
m <- matrix(loc, byrow = TRUE, nrow = nrow(df))

result <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x)df[x,m[x,]]))

colnames(result) <- NULL

result
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]  266  625  707  679  201
# [2,]  894  380  976   62  372
# [3,]  374  572  940  760  204
# [4,]  763  175  906  657  491
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
indices <- cbind( rep(1:nrow(df), each=ncol(df)), as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", loc)) )
matrix(df[indices], nrow(df), byrow = TRUE)

#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]  266  625  707  679  201
#[2,]  894  380  976   62  372
#[3,]  374  572  940  760  204
#[4,]  763  175  906  657  491
```